# Non-printing characters showing up in terminal prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, colors, prompt

Without color my prompt looks like this:

```
[0] [dimo414@dimo414:/tmp]
$ echo $PS1 | sed 's/\x1b/\\e/g'
\n[0] [dimo414@dimo414:/tmp]\n\$
```

I add some color and `\[`...`\]` delimit it:

```
[0] [dimo414@dimo414:/tmp]
$ echo $PS1 | sed 's/\x1b/\\e/g'
\n[\[\e[32m\]0\[\e[0m\]] [\[\e[34m\]dimo414\[\e[0m\]\[\e[32m\]@dimo414\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[94m\]/tmp\[\e[0m\]]\n\$
```

[image: Original Prompt]

Looks great! But the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053) points out that:

> The \[ \] are only special when you assign PS1, if you print them inside a function that runs when the prompt is displayed it doesn't work. In this case you need to use the bytes \001 and \002

However when I change my prompt to use `\001` and `\002` instead, I get this (StackExchange appears to correctly renders them as zero-width characters, but they're there):

```
[0] [dimo414@dimo414:/tmp]
$ echo $PS1 | sed 's/\x1b/\\e/g'
\n[\e[32m0\e[0m] [\e[34mdimo414\e[0m\e[32m@dimo414\e[0m:\e[94m/tmp\e[0m]\n\$
```

[image: New, broken prompt]

This same prompt - with `\001`...`\002` - looks correct in iTerm2 on OSX.

I'm using these two commands to escape the color sequences:

```
# Previously (works)
printf '\[%s\]' "$(color "$@")"

# Currently (doesn't work on Ubuntu)
printf '\001%s\002' "$(color "$@")"
```

What should I be doing instead of the second option in order to use `\001`...`\002` on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think it's because `gnome-terminal` can display Unicode chars. `\001` and `\002` are Unicode escapes.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju using `\001` and `\002` works in other Unicode-supporting terminals (e.g. iTerm2).

Comment: I'd say there's something missing in your prompt probably. By the way, Unicode isn't  `\001` , those are octal values. Unicode in `printf ` is `\uHHHH` Only that doesn't seem to work with `printf` - there's some kind of bug in `printf`.

Comment: @serg any idea what sort of something might be missing?

Comment: Upstreamed: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765992

Comment: @Serg Claming that something written in octal (e.g. \001) is not Unicode whereas something written in hex (e.g. \uHHHH) is is fundamentally wrong. And there's no bug here in printf either.

Comment: @egmont I'm not claiming that. What i do claim is that printf recognizes Unicode with a specific escape sequences. Check printf man page

Comment: As for the bug, there is one. I'm on mobile right now, but I'll link the thread to the issue when i get to my laptop